# Use Flow to update 'added by' field when specific user edits another field

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that runs on the update to determine if the account is a 'VIP' status. For example, if an account has spent over $100 then that account and that account's parent and any 'sibling accounts' account will also be 'VIP'.

I have a get records to retrieve all of the related accounts, then loop the accounts, Assign the value of VIP, add to the collection, then update all the records in the collection. This is working well.

The team has come to me with a new requirement. They want the ability for specific users to edit the status field to VIP manually. Then add the name of the user that made the change to an 'added by' field.

For example, an account has only spent $95. The manager has determined they want the account to have VIP status anyways. So he manually updates the status field to VIP on the page layout. His name should appear in the 'Added by' field.

The inverse needs to work as well. For example, an account spent $150. The manager determined they want the account should have 'Downgraded from VIP' status. So he manually updates the status field on the page layout. This name should appear in the 'added by' field.

I am not sure how to add the new requirement to my current flow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.